# Client side paging on Jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid, paging, client-side

could anyone tell me how to implement client side paging on jqgrid?
Currently, my pager just shows one page which is an error. However, if I change the number of records per page using the drop down, the grid is updated accordingly. But I am unable to navigate thru the pages.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you fill the grid in the wrong way. You don't included any code in your question, so I can only guess that you use `addRowData` method to fill the grid. If it's so, then you should know that the usage of `addRowData` method it the worst and the slowest way to fill the grid which I know.

The best way in case of `datatype: 'local'` is to use `data` option of jqGrid in combination with `gridview: true`. It sorts the data from the `data` parameter corresponds with `sortname` and `sortorder` options, create jqGrid and display the first page of the grid (the size of the page defines `rowNum` option). The value of `data` parameter should be array of items which represent the grid rows. Every item should contains properties with the names like the `name` property of `colModel`. Additionally every item of `data` should contains `id` property which unique value will be used as `id` attribute of rows (`id` of `<tr>` elements).